# git urlencode some characters

Tags: git, url, gitblit

I just changed from svn to git.

I use gitblit as a team git server.
Usually it works perfectly.

But when I fork some project into my account, the repository url looks like "http://git.somewhere.com/~myid/project.git".

It's ok with windows and ubuntu packaged git client.
But when it comes to manually compiled git(I tried 1.7.x, 1.8.x), git client encodes the url like "http://git.somewhere.com/%7Emyid/project.git"

tild(~) is changed to %7E.

Because of this, I cannot use the forked project in some linux machines(actually deployment machines). Linux distro is CentOS 5.9.

How can I fix this problem??

Comment: What's the actual problem/error you're encountering? AFAIK encoding tildes as `%7E` is what it should be doing

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug in gitblit. I would outline the steps to reproduce and put them on  gitblit's issues page

http://code.google.com/p/gitblit/issues/list

I found a similar bug with a gitblit competitor
https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/issue/347/ya-subversion-canonical-path-assertion

Comment: I also think that it could be a bug of gitblit.
But some git client does not encode ~, and some others do.
So I wonder How can I make git client not to encode ~.

Comment: This is a bug in Gitblit, and as answered by @spuder, it would have been helpful if this had been reported to the Gitblit project.  Luckily I happened to pick today to scan StackOverflow Q's (I rarely do this) and I have pushed a fix which will be included in 1.3.1 at some point later today. https://code.google.com/p/gitblit/issues/detail?id=278